# I am trying to add payment method to google cloud console getting the error This action couldn’t be completed. Try again later. [OR_BACR2_34]

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've been trying for two days adding a payment method to Google Cloud Console but continue getting the error below:

This action couldn’t be completed. Try again later. [OR_BACR2_34]

Does anybody know how to bypass the said error?

I was trying to add a payment method to my cloud console account but it continues to fail.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/support/billing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as customer service question are off-topic.

Comment: What did your bank / credit card company say about the failed transaction(s)? What type of payment method and from which country?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this conversation](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Cloud-Hub/GCP-Free-Trial-Sign-Up-Error-OR-BACR2-34-Help/m-p/617406) in the GCP "Cloud Hub" cloud forum.

One suggestion that the rep made was to confirm that this is not a card that requires 2-step verification to use. Because 2SV requires your intervention when a transaction occurs using it, it's not suitable for use in recurring transactions like subscriptions or autopay transactions.

You might also confirm with the bank that it allows subscription-style transactions on the card you are using.

Finally, you can find additional (perhaps helpful?) info at the [Billing guide for updating payment methods](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#add_a_payment_method).