google cloud This action couldn’t be completed. Try again later. [OR_BACR2_34]
I am trying to start a free trail plan on google cloud console but it doesn't accept any visa card card. It shows me the same

This action couldn’t be completed. Try again later. [OR_BACR2_34]
I've tried vpn, three different visa card, different browser and different devices but nothing works


Customer related questions are off-topic here. You should ask directly to GCP billing support

Refer to same question asked before - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78244478/i-am-trying-to-add-payment-method-to-google-cloud-console-getting-the-error-this?rq=2

In my case, it was du to the 2 MFA ( https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) Once configured, I was able to add my card.
Regards,

Maybe your card had been already used for Google Workspace trial or Google Cloud before.

I have this issue too. After some search, I find that it's probably due to the type of the card. Pre-paid card is easily denied by such services.
A possible solution is: use Mastercard instead of Visa.
Reason: Visa has a so-called "Decision Manager" algorithm that decides whether to pass your verification or not (fraud or not). And this algorithm is owned by Visa.
